# Program called to run via wine within a node.js script freezes

Tags: node.js, bash, wine

Program called to run via wine within a node.js script freezes as soon as it starts to do it's task.

This is the `top` output:
[image]

It runs fine and display the cli's header if I call it without parameters.

But if use it with arguments it hangs as soon as it starts to display progress and continuous stdout (eg: the ones where the only thing that is updated in the screen is the percentage of the current task)

Tried with `exec`, `execSync`, `spawnSync`, `spawn`.
Also tried to `spawn` and `spawnSync` a .sh file calling it (with and without `&` `disown`)

I think it has something to do with some child_process or even environment limitations, because I was able to do it by calling wine from a new gnome-terminal with parameters. But then I get an extra terminal window popping up, and no control whatsoever about the task conclusion.

Does anyone have a solution or a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was related to `stdio`

No idea why, but setting
`{stdio: ['inherit', 'pipe', 'pipe']}` to `.spawn()` for Ubuntu and OSX did the trick.