# How to open a .exe file on Linux Hosted NodeJS

Tags: node.js, linux, wine

I am attempting to have my node server launch a .exe file on a Linux hosted implementation of NODEJS

My .exe is located here: `'/home/username/projects/ProjectName/server/webserver/Project.exe'`

and when I attempt to start the exe

with:

```
   exec('/home/username/projects/ProjectName/server/webserver/Project.exe', ["/home/username/projects/ProjectName/server/webserver/files/"+date], function(err, data) {
}
```

i am getting a file not fond error

that looks like this:

```
{ Error: Command failed: /home/username/projects/ProjectName/server/webserver/Project.exe /home/username/projects/ProjectName/server/webserver/files/31005
/home/username/projects/ProjectName/server/webserver/Project.exe: 1: /home/username/projects/ProjectName/server/webserver/Project.exe: MZ�##���@�#��: not found
/home/username/projects/ProjectName/server/webserver/Project.exe: 2: /home/username/projects/ProjectName/server/webserver/Project.exe: Syntax error: ")" unexpected

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:389:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:606:12)
  killed: false,
  code: 2,
  signal: null,
  cmd:
   '/home/username/projects/ProjectName/server/webserver/Project.exe /home/username/projects/ProjectName/server/webserver/files/31005' }
```

When attempting to run the same function on a windows based NodeJS with windows directories instead of linux it works, the file can be opened via Wine on Linux, is there somewhere in my function call where i need to direct it to open the .exe with WINE? If so how do I go about doing that?

Comment: So you are trying to run a Windows executable on Linux? Is that right?

Comment: that is correct Rob,

Comment: Why would you think a Windows binary would run on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const { exec} = require('child_process');
 exec('wine /home/username/projects/ProjectName/server/webserver/Project.exe /home/username/projects/ProjectName/server/webserver/files/'+date,
function(err, data){

});
```

https://superuser.com/questions/1058985/launch-program-with-wine-using-exe-arguments
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49069169/12167785

Comment: So, now its giving me ENOENT (file not found)

I think for some reason when it's calling the function it's leaving the quotation marks, as part of the error log shows:

  cmd:
   'wine /home/aaronmanill/projects/Pizzabox/pizzaboxwebsite/server/webserver/Pizza_page_server.exe 31528' 

If i try to run it with quotes in terminal i get the same error, but if i run it without quotes in the terminal it runs properly

Comment: @AaronManill try running exec('wine') and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

I got my desired functionality using the following:

```
exec("wine", ["/home/username/projects/ProjectName/server/webserver/Project.exe", date], function(err,data){
}
```